# PHP getting array foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some problems with getting array on Laravel framework.
I have response like this when I var_dump selected (var_dummp in view)

```
array(6) { [0]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(156) "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1PsZyqbSYBuNjSspiq6xNzpXaj/Popular-2-pcs-Ponytail-Creator-Plastic-Loop-Styling-Tools-Black-Topsy-Pony-topsy-Tail-Clip-Hair.jpg" } [1]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(156) "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1rhIRdIj_B1NjSZFHq6yDWpXaG/Popular-2-pcs-Ponytail-Creator-Plastic-Loop-Styling-Tools-Black-Topsy-Pony-topsy-Tail-Clip-Hair.jpg" } [2]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(156) "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1h0DQnbSYBuNjSspiq6xNzpXay/Popular-2-pcs-Ponytail-Creator-Plastic-Loop-Styling-Tools-Black-Topsy-Pony-topsy-Tail-Clip-Hair.jpg" } [3]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(156) "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1BGEOnf5TBuNjSspmq6yDRVXao/Popular-2-pcs-Ponytail-Creator-Plastic-Loop-Styling-Tools-Black-Topsy-Pony-topsy-Tail-Clip-Hair.jpg" } [4]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(156) "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1RzEeXuUXBuNjt_XBq6xeDXXaP/Popular-2-pcs-Ponytail-Creator-Plastic-Loop-Styling-Tools-Black-Topsy-Pony-topsy-Tail-Clip-Hair.jpg" } [5]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(156) "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1wgyLe8yWBuNkSmFPq6xguVXa1/Popular-2-pcs-Ponytail-Creator-Plastic-Loop-Styling-Tools-Black-Topsy-Pony-topsy-Tail-Clip-Hair.jpg" } }
```

And when I want to foreach that array I'm writing like this.

```py
@foreach ($images as  image)
<li><img src="{{ $image['url'] }}" class="img-fluid w-100" alt="Image Title"></li>
@endforeach
```

and it's giving error

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '[' (View: C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\ecomet-html\resources\views\product_info.blade.php)
```

Why?

Comment: Why? Because of `$`.

Comment: You forgot the `$` on image: `@foreach ($images as  image)`

Comment: $ is missing from loop declaration